# In vue bootstrap i try use v-slot ceil for add edit/delete button but it's not working

Tags: vuejs2

i try to add edit/delete button in vue bootstrap table but it's not working

```
<b-table
    id="my-table"
    responsive="sm"
    :head-variant="headVariant"
    :items="items"
    :fields="fields"
    :per-page="perPage"
    :current-page="currentPage"
    small
  >
    <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
      <b-button>{{row}}</b-button>
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

this is the fields:

```
fields: ["price", "open", "high", "low", "vol", "change", "actions"],
```

Comment: what are u doing here by adding button inside table ?

Comment: What version of `Bootstrap-Vue` are you using? Also, what do you mean with "It's not working", can you be a bit more descriptive?